# ¿Cómo crear un objeto en java sin escribir el nombre de la clase? (Usando solo new)

Tags: java, poo

¡Buenas!, tengo una duda algo tonta:

Sé que hay múltiples formas para crear un objeto, la que yo aprendí fue la siguiente:

```
NombreDeLaClase objeto = new NombreDeLaClase();
```

Hasta este punto nada nuevo, pero recientemente vi un tutorial para la creación de GUI's con swing en la que en la clase principal hacían una especie de instancia sólo usando new:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creo un objeto de la clase MainFrame.
        new MainFrame();

    }

}
```

La clase a la que hacen referencia con new MainFrame(); es la siguiente:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    public MainFrame() {
        super("MainFrame");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Por lo que pude ver el código funciona perfectamente (sólo haría falta agregar el método para volverla visible).

Mi duda es: ¿Es una forma correcta de hacer instancias de una clase?, ¿qué ventajas y desventajas tiene esta forma de hacer las cosas?

¡Saludos! y gracias por vuestra atención.

Comment: yo veo que ambos metodos son iguales, solo que en el primero se guarda la referencia del objeto

Comment: Y para hacer visible esa ventana puedes hacerlo así `new MainFrame().setVisible(true);`. La cuestión es si vas a necesitar ese objeto para algo

Comment: ¡Muchas a gracias a todos por las respuestas!, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Hay una diferencia muy clara, y como dice Diego'L depende si vas a usar esa instancia o no. Con esta respuesta pretendo ampliar esa.

Si instancias un objeto de una clase descendiente de Frame sin mantener una referencia, cuando el usuario cierre ese frame ya no tendrás acceso a ninguna variable miembro de esa instancia. Normalmente se trata de programas principales, o en general de acciones que por su propio comportamiento ya resultan suficientes en la aplicación. Si en cambio, queremos obtener alguna información después de que el usuario haya cerrado el frame, entonces es preciso mantener la referencia de la instancia. Ejemplos claros son los diálogos de apertura o escritura de ficheros, que después que el usuario haya aceptado, y una vez desaparecida la ventana, obtenemos aún el valor del fichero seleccionado.

Filosóficamente, es la misma diferencia que entre instrucción y expresión, y también análoga a la diferencia entre función y procedimiento. Una instrucción, o un procedimiento, tienen sentido por sí solos. Es como una frase con sujeto, verbo y complemento. Una expresión,  o una función no tienen sentido por sí solos. Una expresión es tan sólo una parte de una frase.

Cuando no se referencia la instancia es como llamar a un procedimiento que retorne void. Cuando se referencia, és para obtener resultados como si de una función se tratase.

Answer (score 0):

Para instanciar (crear) objetos de una determinada clase (estándar de Java, creada por nosotros, o por un tercero) podemos encontrarnos con distintas formas que debemos aplicar. La más habitual de ellas es utilizar la palabra reservada new, siguiendo el siguiente formato:

```
new NombreDeLaClase()
```

Esto sería una llamada al método constructor de la clase. Este tipo de llamada nos devuelven una instancia u objeto de dicha clase. Una vez creado el objeto, podemos guardarlo en una variable o utilizarlo dentro de cualquier expresión compatible con la clase del objeto creado.

Para declarar una variable que pueda contener un objeto de una determinada clase se actúa de forma similar a la declaración de las variables habituales, es decir, siguiendo la estructura:

```
NombreDeLaClase nombreDeLaVariable;
```

Es muy habitual que a la vez que se declara una variable, se cree un objeto de su misma clase y se le asigne a dicha variable, formando una sentencia completa de la siguiente forma:

```
NombreDeLaClase nombreDeLaVariable = new NombreDeLaClase();
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias amigo!, perfecta explicación, saludos.