# Diferencia de invocación de una interfaz en Java

Tags: java, poo

Necesito saber cual es la diferencia en hacer la invocación de una interfaz de las siguientes maneras:

```
ClaseEJ clase = new ClaseEJ();
clase.setVisible(true);
```

Frente a:

```
new ClaseEJ().setVisible(true);
```

No se si la diferencia este en el constructor, simplemente no entiendo en qué se diferencian y si invocar de una manera afecta el programa diferente a la otra manera

Comment: Hola! Probaste las dos opciones? Qué pasó en cada caso?

Comment: La diferencia es que en la primera guardas la referencia en una variable y en la segunda no. ¿Cuál usar? Pues depende, si nunca vas a usar la variable `clase`, quédate con la segunda opción, de lo contrario, con la primera.

Comment: Alfabravo si he utilizado ambas opciones pero no veo una diferencia clara. @MrDave1999 Gracias por el dato, solo me preocupaba, pense que afectaba el constructor

Comment: @JuanPabloCortesMoncada A nivel de sintaxis si hay diferencia (la que comenté), pero en tiempo de ejecución no, ambos casos crean un objeto y tampoco afecta nada al constructor. Mira este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/254407/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-objeto-en-java-sin-escribir-el-nombre-de-la-clase-usando-solo-n), tal vez te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Internamente para Java no hay diferencia alguna, en ambos casos creas un objeto el cual es almacenado en memoria, la única diferencia es la utilidad que le dará el programador, es decir, imaginemos que utilizas la sentencia `new ClaseEJ().setVisible(true);` y posteriormente por X necesidad necesitas asignar a ese mismo objeto un nuevo valor, el hecho es que como programador no podrás hacerlo puesto que no tienes como invocarlo en algún otro lugar de tu código. El escenario que te planteo realmente no es un problema ya que aun así puedes declarar el objeto como una "clase anónima" dándote la libertad de asignarle múltiples valores al objeto que utilizas en cuestión.

Si quieres saber mas sobre "clases anónimas" puedes consultar:
[Clases anonimas](http://www.hijosdelspectrum.com/2019/01/clases-anonimas.html)